# "Select All" option in drop down - Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ngselect

[Need to know to code like the one in the image "Select All" Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTJ87.png)How to display "Select All" option in a drop down box which displays a array of list in it

I tried adding a ng-select-option as Select All which didn't work at all, like the one below

```
<ng-select-option [value]="'all'">
            <input id="select-all-checkbox" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectAll" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" /> Select All
</ng-select-option>
```